# c# IQueryable<T>.Take method is not limiting result on EF6 entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using linq and EntityFramework 6 to limit the number of records returned from database.

My test table, `AuditLogs`, has a total of 20 records.

**If I write:**

```cs
var auditLogsList = context.AuditLogs.Take(10); // Type is IQueryable<AuditLog>
var listValues = auditLogsList.ToList();
var count = listValues.Count; // Correct output = 10
```

I get `listValues.Count` equals to 10, which is the expected output.

But, I don't know why, **if I call method Take in the next line**:

```cs
var auditLogsList = context.AuditLogs; // Type is IQueryable<AuditLog>
auditLogsList.Take(10);
var listValues = auditLogsList.ToList();
var count = listValues.Count; // Wrong output = 20
```

I get `listValues.Count` equals to 20, which is the total number of records of the table and it's not what I expect.

I need to use it the second way.

**Any ideas if it's a bug or am I missing something here?**

Note: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and Entity Framework 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
auditLogsList.Take(10);
```

Just creates an enumerator over 10 items - but you don't assign this anywhere, so it's thrown away.

Later on you do this:

```
var listValues = auditLogsList.ToList();
```

This is working with the whole list - hence why you get 20.

If you just want to take 10 items (as a list), you can change the above line to:

```
var listValues = auditLogsList.Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: My mistake. That's it! You answered it first, so I should accept it. In order to clarify the answer for others, could you please edit your answer showing an example of the right way as @Berkay did?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are using `Take` wrong. As MSDN link says that [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx) will *Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence.* So you need to set it to a variable.

```
var auditLogsList = context.AuditLogs; 
auditLogsList = auditLogsList.Take(10);
var listValues = auditLogsList.ToList();
var count = listValues.Count; // output = 10
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Your link points to the wrong Take, you want [`Queryable.Take(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks Scott. Updated.